# Calling NSString in another void method issue

Tags: ios, nsstring, uipickerview

I am trying to call NSSting into a void method but I am getting **EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error.** What would be causing this?

I have made a brakepoint(debug) to NSLog in btnPickerDoneTouchHandler but choiceList is empty.

**.H:**

```
@interface controlView : UIViewController{
      NSString *choiceList;
}
```

**.M:**

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{

    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    return [res count];
}



-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    return [[res objectAtIndex:row]objectForKey:@"choice_name"];   
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
      choiceList = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<r_PM act='closepos_choice' cl_choice='%d'/>", row];

      NSLog(@"You have selected row %@", choiceList);
}


- (void)btnPickerDoneTouchHandler{
      //I have put here the brakepoint.
      NSLog(@"choiceList is %@", choiceList);
}
```

Comment: do you use ARC or Manual Memory Management?

Comment: If you are not using ARC then make property and synthesize for choiceList string.

Comment: No I am not using ARC

Comment: Even if you are using arc it's better practice to use properties instead of ivars.

Comment: I have used property and synthesize it is still giving me EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error.

Comment: @Luai Kalkatawi: please check my answer may it will works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

In your .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString  * choiceList;
```

In your .m file

```
@synthesize choiceList;

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
  self.choiceList = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<r_PM act='closepos_choice' cl_choice='%d'/>", row];

  NSLog(@"You have selected row %@", self.choiceList);
}


- (void)btnPickerDoneTouchHandler{
    //I have put here the brakepoint.
    NSLog(@"choiceList is %@", self.choiceList);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

.H:

```
@interface controlView : UIViewController 
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString  * choiceList;
```

.M:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
      self.choiceList = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<r_PM act='closepos_choice' cl_choice='%d'/>", row];

      NSLog(@"You have selected row %@", choiceList);
}


- (void)btnPickerDoneTouchHandler{
      //I have put here the brakepoint.
      NSLog(@"choiceList is %@", self.choiceList);
}
```

**OR:**

You need to `alloc` your string to get access to it within the class:

```
  choiceList = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"<r_PM act='closepos_choice' cl_choice='%d'/>", row];
```

Answer (score 0):

just create a **@property** in .h file such like,

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString  * choiceList;
```